# Why is my Neovim not in English and how do I force it to be?

Tags: neovim

I'm using Neovim 0.2.2 on macOS High Sierra (10.13.1), installed via `brew install neovim`.

I removed `.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Neovim starts up using German for interface labels, as shown here:

[image: German labels in Neovim interface]

Here's the output of `locale`:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Here are my "Language & Region" settings:

[image: macOS Language & Region Settings]

All my other applications, GUI or command line, are in English.

Can someone enlighten me on what is causing Neovim to display German interface labels and how I can override that to use English instead?

I searched the Neovim documentation and Google on how to manually set Neovim's interface language, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Is this not relevant? https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5873

Comment: It is! I think I had skimmed that issue but disqualified it at being about something different too hastily... But in the last comment someone actually provides a nice solution that doesn't mess with the environment: putting `language en_US` in `.config/nvim/init.vim`. Thanks! If you want to post it as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

1. Open `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` (or create it if not present)
2. Add a line `language en_US`
3. Save it and reload Neovim

I would like to give all the credits to @anothernode. I've just convert his comment into the regular answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the second part of my question: just after posting I had the ingenious idea of setting `LANG=en_US` and that actually works.

Just out of curiosity, I'd still be interested in the answer to the first part: where exactly did Neovim get the idea to use German instead of defaulting to English in the first place?

Comment: Should be fixed by https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/7704