# How do I change my language in my init.lua? - neovim

Tags: neovim, lua, init

I've got the problem that the neovim language is set to German for some reason even though I only use a German keyboard layout ([see this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/why-is-my-neovim-not-in-english-and-how-do-i-force-it-to-be)). Unfortunately I am using lua for configuring neovim (the linked question provides an answer for `init.vim` configs) and even though I tried some things, I cannot figure out how to convert `language en_US` to valid lua code.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`vim.api.nvim_exec()`](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#vimapinvim_exec) (or `vim.cmd()` if your NeoVim version still doesn't have it) to run Vimscript commands from Lua.

```
vim.api.nvim_exec('language en_US')
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Neovim require an additional boolean parameter to set the language, so, this would be the proper command in `init.lua`:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_exec ('language en_US', true)
```